# JavaFX switching scenes with different sizes

Tags: user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scene

I was testing [jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea)'s work with his small JavaFX [framework](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6460130) and i was wondering how is  it possible to adapt it to change view between scene of different sizes ? Because so far i know, every changed scene fits the main Vbox size.

**Edit :** Here are some things i've tried with sizeToScene()

On Main.java

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        stage.setTitle("Vista Viewer");

        stage.setScene(
            createScene(
                loadMainPane()
            )
        );
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }
```

Or on MainController.java

```
public void setVista(Node node) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) vistaHolder.getScene().getWindow();
        vistaHolder.getChildren().setAll(node);
        stage.sizeToScene();
    }
```

I understand how the first example isn't right since it's happening only once, but what about the second ?

Comment: Have you tried `stage.sizeToScene();` ?

Comment: Yes, but when i try to use it, it's throwing exceptions. Or maybe i didn't put it at the right place (tried several ways though).

Comment: Can you add a code snippet to your question so as to show what have you tried.

Comment: `stage.sizeToScene();` should be used after `stage.show();`, other than this I cannot identify any potential mistake in your code. Actually, the code that you have added to the question just shows the usage of the statements. I would advice you to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the issue. *You can also create the MCVE without using the framework.*